# Is it possible to triangulate a mapping cone of simplicial map

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

In Weibel homological algebra,there is a claim that if $f:L\rightarrow K$ is inclusion between simplicial complex,then there is a natual way to triangulate mapping cone $C_{f}$.Is there any problems when it comes to general case?

Comment: Can you write your question more precisely?

Comment: i want to get if f is just a simplicial  map ,not inclusion.then can we find triangulation of mapping cone based on L and K